# How do I add or modify attributes on objects before passing them to a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm not quite sure how to go about this problem. I want to create a view where a user enters a date range and the list of ledgers updates to display balance for that date range. The ledgers are in categories and the categories should also show their balance.

This is how far I've got.

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Ledger
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def calculate_balance(self, date_from, date_to):
        """Gives balance based on date range"""
        money_out = LineItem.objects.filter(ledger=self.id, journal_entry__date__range=[date_from, date_to]).aggregate(Sum('money_out'))
        money_in = LineItem.objects.filter(ledger=self.id, journal_entry__date__range=[date_from, date_to]).aggregate(Sum('money_in'))
        if money_out['money_out__sum'] == None:
            money_out['money_out__sum'] = 0
        if money_in['money_in__sum'] == None:
            money_in['money_in__sum'] = 0
        balance = round(money_in['money_in__sum'] - money_out['money_out__sum'],2)
        return balance

class LineItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    ledger = models.ForeignKey(Ledger, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    money_out = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    money_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Template.html

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li>{{category.name}} - {{category.balance}}</li>
            <ul>
                {% for ledger in category.ledger_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ ledger.name }} - {{ ledger.balance }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

views.py
Does not work. I've calculated the ledger balance correctly according to date range but can't pass the balance to the view. And haven't figured out how to calculate the category balance yet.

```
def report_balance(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    ... # Some logic to create a form that gets the from and to dates.
    for category in categories:
        for ledger in category.ledger_set.all():
            ledger.balance = ledger.calculate_balance(form.cleaned_data['from_date'],form.cleaned_data['to_date'])

    form = SelectDatesForm()
    return render(request, 'journal/template.html',{'categories': categories, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're roughly on the right track, but I believe that your call to `category.ledger_set.all` in the template is re-issuing the query. Instead, you want to preserve the modified `ledger` objects under some name you can use in the template. Something like:

```
for category in categories:
   category.ledgers_with_balances = []
   for ledger in category.ledger_set.all():
       ledger.balance = ledger.calculate_balance(form.cleaned_data['from_date'],form.cleaned_data['to_date'])
       category.ledgers_with_balances.append(ledger)
```

Then in your template:
`{% for ledger in category.ledgers_with_balances %}`

I believe that's all that's necessary, because iterating over the initial `categories` queryset causes the view to evaluate it. `categories` is still a queryset, but further iteration (or slicing or whatever else) won't cause it to be reevaluated.

You could also build the behavior into the `category` model if it's generalizable, but I think the above is fine if it's a one-off.

Similarly, you can set whatever other data you want on the `Category` instances before passing them into the context:

```
    for ledger in category.ledger_set.all():
        #... as above
    category.balance = sum(ledger.balance for ledger in category.ledgers_with_balances)
```

Or whatever the math is - the point is that when your template iterates over the `categories` queryset it'll get the same actual Python instances as your view iteration. Including any modifactions you made in the view.

Comment: Hi Peter. I tried your code but the following line errors:

`category.ledgers_with_balances.append(ledger)`

Error:
`'Category' object has no attribute 'ledgers_with_balances'`

Comment: @rcx935 Did you initialize it to an empty list, as I showed above before the `for ledger in category.ledger_set.all():`? `category.ledgers_with_balances = []`

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! It works now. Nice going, thank you!